# Python getopt - How do I check for different possible combinations of arguments?

Tags: python, command-line, getopt

How to I use getopt so that I can check for every valid combination of 2 argumentsin every possible order?

Like for example:

```
try:
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"a:b")
except getopt.GetoptError:
  try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"a:c")
  except:
    sys.exit(1)
```

The input could be for example `script.py -a avalue -b bvalue` or `script.py -a avalue -c cvalue`.
The positions of a and the other argument could also be reversed.

But I only get confusing values when executing my script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you may want to look at `argparse` instead. It takes a bit more manual reading to get started, but it can do much more!

With `getopt`, switches are always optional and can always come in any order. I.e, if you do

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "a:b:c:")
```

the user can give `-a avalue`, `-b bvalue`, and `-c cvalue` in any order, and omit any, or all, of them.

Also, notice that `getopt` does not expect to find the program name in the argument list, meaning that you usually want to pass `argv[1:]`.